# sObjectName and lightning quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction

I have a lightning quick action that needs to check the sObjectName to trigger a conditional action that will fill some fields depending on it.

The problem that I encounter is that when using the implements for the lightning quick action and the hasSObjectName the value is empty but I can get the recordId using the same method and there's no error.

```
<aura:component description="ClonePricebook"
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
                flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
                force:lightningQuickAction,
                force:hasRecordId,
                force:hasSObjectName"
                access="global">
<p>{!v.recordId}</p> //Filled
<p>{!v.sObjectName}</p> // Empty
</aura:component>
```

According to the release notes of Summer 17 (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_force_hassobjectname.htm) I should be able to use it inside a quick action.

Why can't I get the sObjectName in this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you re-check this please. Because I tried the exact same code in my org and its working fine.

Please check the screen shots -

[image: Component]

[image: Adding action button]

[image: Click on actin button]

**Note -** Can you check your component version number once. Mine is 40 and it works fine.

Comment: The version was Right, it was 40 from the Start. The only difference is that I created a global action and not an action on that particular (custom) object. 

So Apparently it does not work on a global action.

I am marking you as the right answer as you made me realise and test this situation. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, correct it doesn't work for global action. I didn't knew that you have created global action. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_force_hassobjectname.htm) - you don't need attribute.

Did you declare and attribute for it?

```
<aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
```

Also, is your component bundle version 40?